# Python CSV File, Comparing Time Period

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, time

Link to CSV file: https://www.emcsg.com/marketdata/priceinformation [I download the CSV file of the 72 periods. Every afternoon at 12pm - UTC+08:00, it has a new file which shows the prices for that day and price forecast until 12am of the next day.]

I am trying to display the date and time when the energy(USEP/$MWh) falls below the average of each day.

```
for line in lines:
    try:
        time = line.split(",")[1][1:-1]
        interval = line.split(",")[0][1:-1]
        item = line.split(",")[4][1:-1] #Choose 4th column and delete ""
        if interval == next_day:
          if float(item) < average:
              print interval, time, float(item)

    except:
        pass           #If it can't parse, the string is not a number
```

The above codes prints something like this

```
30 Sep 2017 01:00-01:30 84.14
30 Sep 2017 01:30-02:00 84.12
30 Sep 2017 02:00-02:30 85.11
30 Sep 2017 02:30-03:00 83.49
30 Sep 2017 03:00-03:30 80.66
30 Sep 2017 03:30-04:00 75.69
30 Sep 2017 04:00-04:30 72.45
         .
         .  
         .
30 Sep 2017 21:30-22:00 79.72
30 Sep 2017 22:00-22:30 73.23
30 Sep 2017 22:30-23:00 73.58
30 Sep 2017 23:00-23:30 72.14
30 Sep 2017 23:30-00:00 85.21
```

It shows the date and time of which the price of energy is below the average of 30 Sep.

But I want to print something like that

```
30 Sep 2017 01:00-04:30
30 Sep 2017 21:30-00:00
```

Basically I want to group them up since the time is continuous. Once there is a break (where during that time, price is above average), it will print a new line with the next 'period' when the prices are below average.

I was thinking of comparing the end time of each 'period'(e.g 01:00-01:30, 01:30 is end time) with the start time of the next period (e.g 01:30-02:00, 01:30 is start time) in the next line but I'm not sure if it's feasible.

Thank you in advance!(:

Comment: It's not 100% clear on what you are trying to do

Comment: I think you are doing the right thing. One way to do it: have two variables, start and end.. and if end = start append to list if not create new entry.

Answer (score 1):

This must be one of **my** ugliest codes in a long time. 
But maybe you meant something like this?
With some thinking this could probably be done directly with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.emcsg.com/marketdata/priceinformation?downloadRealtime=true"
df = pd.read_csv(url)

average = df["USEP($/MWh)"].mean()
output = []
entry = 0
old = None

# Starts a loop 
# (if average changes from bigger to lower or vice versa 
# create new entry in the output list)
for k,v in df.iterrows():  

    # First entry
    if not old:
        output.append([])
        output[entry].append(v["Period"])
        if v["USEP($/MWh)"] > average:
            old = "bigger"
            output[0].append(old)
        else:
            old = "smaller"
            output[entry].append(old)
        output[entry].append(v["USEP($/MWh)"])
        continue

    # The rest
    if v["USEP($/MWh)"] > average:
        new = "bigger"
    else:
        new = "smaller"

    if new == old:
        output[entry][0] = output[entry][0].split("-")[0]+"-"+v["Period"].split("-")[1]
        output[entry][2] += v["USEP($/MWh)"]
    else:
        entry += 1
        output.append([])
        output[entry].append(v["Period"])
        output[entry].append(new)
        output[entry].append(v["USEP($/MWh)"])

    old = new
```

output looks like:

```
[['12:00-15:30', 'bigger', 503.52],
 ['15:30-18:30', 'smaller', 423.78],
 ['18:30-00:00', 'bigger', 839.39],
 ['00:00-10:00', 'smaller', 1372.4700000000003],
 ['10:00-11:30', 'bigger', 215.90999999999997],
 ['11:30-13:00', 'smaller', 211.83000000000004],
 ['13:00-17:00', 'bigger', 576.4200000000001],
 ['17:00-20:30', 'smaller', 486.94],
 ['20:30-22:00', 'bigger', 227.11],
 ['22:00-00:00', 'smaller', 271.34000000000003]]
```

Comment: Well, thanks for telling me that my codes are ugly. If I knew how to code well and I'm not just in a situation where I have to learn how to code, I probably wouldn't be asking on this website. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Autumn I would never tell someone his/her code is ugly because people here look for help and I consider myself one that likes to help. I was talking about my code.

Comment: @Autumn if he was saying that your code was ugly then you should've took it with a positive attitude, as he is a more experienced programmer who took the time to answer you. [There is a community](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) whose sole purpose is to let people take your code apart. A passive-aggressive attitude in face of criticism will lead you nowhere in this business. Also, no matter your skill level, you should always be asking questions. Always.

Comment: @AntonvBR Okay, sorry for the misunderstanding. Thanks for helping once again. I appreciate it.